# How to catch a signal properly in C

Tags: c, signals

I been focusing on many ways on catching signals. The latest one being is using a global variable. My aim is to catch control C, when its pressed, it sets a flag to "1" that then triggers some code to run.

my problem is, I can get the signal to be caught. However finding it impossible to run the code that should run in the if statement.

```
void handleSignal (int signal);

int signalAction = 0;

int main ()
{
    //catch signal control C
    if (signal(SIGINT, handleSignal) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        write (2, "Error catching signal C \n", 26);
    }

    if (signalAction == 1)
    {
        write(1, "WOOO CONTROL C \n", 16);
        signalAction = 0;
    }

    printf("%d \n", signalAction);

    while(1)
        sleep(1);   
}

void handleSignal (int signal)
{
    if (signal == SIGINT)
    {
        write(1, "ContrlC \n", 11);
        signalAction = 1;
    }
}
```

When control c is pressed I get "contrlC" printed out from the signal handler. However the if statement in the main function if(signalAction ==1).... doesn't run.

The variable must be set to 1. Is their a issue in main picking it up for some reason?

Comment: Those `write ` calls are weird. Why don't you use the C library? As written, they're not even quite correct, since `write` may write as little as one byte.

Comment: He's probably trying to stick with functions that are signal safe, which to be POSIX-correct includes `write` but NOT `fwrite` (or `printf`).

Comment: Also, you might want to look at `sigaction` instead of `signal`.  Generally, `sigaction` is waaaay more powerful / flexible and what you'll want to use in any real production code.  And yet another option, (maybe Linux only) is a `signalfd`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your `if(signalAction ==1)` inside while loop

Comment: Thanks for that...stupid mistake. Would you recommend this practice for handling signals by using global variables?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. In many cases the signal handler may call other function(s), setting a global value is not a good practice - in a multi-threaded env. Also you may want to reinstall the signal handler again after catching the signal.